# Parallel Full table scan with cassandra golang

Tags: cassandra

We need to list all records present in one of our cassandra table, with no other technological alternative available other than cassandra kafka , may be Redis or Memcache.

I have tried using token function fr implementing the same but there are 256 tokens for each cassandra cluster node and the tokens for the actual data will be between those range , to generate so many queries for a single node multiplied by the total nodes in the cluster is not feasible and a good solution.

Also tried with Redis but it also doesnot support full data fetch for all keys and there is a consistency problem with Redic for full scan.

The approach should list all records in cassandra

Token Range for a single node of cassandra there are 4 such nodes how can i define valid ranges with this:
 tokens          | {'-110767653085527406', '-11899237173434452', '-1391588707809180381', '-1394091128308441003', '-1454290790206147221', '-146581343968211882', '-1510367355435659988', '-1597335133622403317', '-1624081458138081415', '-168229075262213001', '-181492943272452920', '-1880973887796347199', '-1928606638447682076', '-1996927792402687332', '-2040293875245386739', '-2254793999558778584', '-22839319021629861', '-2331554848249702104', '-2379869377033037910', '-2415502069923563625', '-242505702341187347', '-2554870378500275896', '-2581963426036313684', '-2597277185289252380', '-270600990255590679', '-2769295379248843049', '-2773593424004668662', '-2779088327300923185', '-2882600279826978153', '-2902635794027806253', '-2934498214552531684', '-2952580781415168081', '-2976075019979540496', '-2976245638239977177', '-2983412321816148828', '-3109933176533204424', '-311846787798501197', '-3124939076761231316', '-3207861261030143293', '-3238862798824218873', '-33867353014374856', '-3553724852857338260', '-3560673059960522188', '-356648548720270905', '-362063928226840505', '-37058745295809774', '-3742275433208587070', '-3749955156988962773', '-3900882761202798088', '-3973974971666104363', '-398705848522233876', '-4053569000187706804', '-4074367680485751199', '-4095792766539323822', '-4096319368982665252', '-4129903903790768590', '-4307779691882475614', '-4335822085973976571', '-4341227537672046651', '-4512200475571998217', '-4534717518849679193', '-4779704075219767017', '-4784311089903325584', '-4801774998664423639', '-4804212231957235493', '-483770716427992088', '-4961119884427575269', '-5067995934113824964', '-5179591373759173007', '-5222898906811438602', '-525332699787023615', '-5301216212942836549', '-5310317000187572515', '-5319819741815758513', '-5406874697769855545', '-5434192774073302155', '-5511437742387618420', '-5569182247670740374', '-5613734126964485310', '-5695753794996236661', '-5709302843132412852', '-5764537668560605366', '-5821065912874338783', '-5863279366209886565', '-5934987261590356264', '-6133292976907132372', '-613918942431504582', '-617013752066297090', '-6382944484166916340', '-6466434510742133122', '-6469626679024796986', '-6503973804378181126', '-6588579521459992719', '-6836323321210332702', '-6889082380849183152', '-6925696393204831908', '-6958388753424715358', '-6981851521917267920', '-7026337701757077840', '-7034132335887364270', '-7177735139862626910', '-7217360169581796062', '-7250937350023353107', '-7254646596009961697', '-7273632288923135942', '-7681132805636687468', '-7684247424411677445', '-7719782854902809160', '-7722083163709043350', '-7883299635842594745', '-7884312097637684222', '-7932425995667387119', '-7933674004938295880', '-8003457508869571744', '-8012655526874157873', '-8088662569140472983', '-8089205747576449546', '-8110588364712294426', '-8143388211436035425', '-8154888661271397662', '-8216640585517555216', '-8363836864913573316', '-8387521487575455032', '-8514021467895643262', '-8562505084525044114', '-8605932634242447791', '-8627927601309539397', '-8781781221565097029', '-8826509744879101903', '-8829454439683469998', '-9060982903379845955', '-9077133642827708596', '-9103192004889706679', '-9161286921784303754', '-9173290295023729766', '-9202549283493769631', '-946825098300134575', '-985939805189037504', '1051371888105587236', '1179367297935764236', '1232222457632414798', '1250821404055945417', '1260552460427800308', '1330858755796015498', '1343386869233046957', '1416897686092659608', '1566479564079439007', '1751929023649226956', '1983332469209775985', '1991590117501237767', '2079091014003321437', '209817188594064906', '2227942341204832007', '2364752846080807659', '2384045839366872301', '245703437154148550', '2619183027115062748', '2643406976828815155', '2767300599666575624', '2960862668765972823', '3093398863419321623', '3147898346818654417', '323290155938151040', '3270693391160699545', '3272561623580700082', '3337607373305853720', '3342959566488433792', '3374600727832246512', '3492931041298713575', '3526040977939287418', '3590457424347478577', '3703008661325389509', '3705820410499710106', '3829082654461929531', '38672415515190730', '4011768573695751893', '4288242512566344183', '4550689156828245294', '4727167529636264869', '47496744286251620', '4782071184201611983', '4830336407465180494', '4835868359539472429', '4846746833382764940', '4975166681749963090', '4984830052240405637', '5175857549446124752', '5189207299783812170', '5213957910371403883', '5276806365656383699', '5334108094034916975', '5346658874365534505', '5350376569297936111', '5397358255276785420', '5439965368180564946', '5502246143195934054', '5574932980912993360', '56339286104975805', '567123899521905676', '5697905565184472939', '5733133555368835034', '5839216959068788722', '5849639838922928470', '5873721226954660761', '5942069210343820345', '6089870738989393030', '6091594696190765377', '6094019777779399599', '6139319371529794750', '621323007188797312', '6229127889800318515', '6234544190010010273', '6279368061674915925', '6298490213677918283', '6329370832225226002', '6329458732474081843', '6346560530861696360', '646927984547524601', '6472602971501415760', '6675656389057164855', '6752332711499618514', '6768402617936061566', '68540305057271675', '6918893643695601347', '7069981246789501654', '7145714029036953461', '7305513927425596150', '7353680600558295278', '7385719102005103560', '7514365100340213306', '7548719020866764605', '756345585078159614', '7743033418223242963', '7781933260936336072', '7887990247458547999', '7953895213828635565', '8022938827862376937', '812789197848120460', '8135520527417264202', '8186619481104495679', '8187771638081436991', '8189206199997031942', '8292652364304849642', '8383626225554909864', '8498860882761442441', '8717375307224044802', '8719782819012004616', '8781046959001311087', '885633447090523324', '8892282984535947868', '890767229038640710', '8923676315945778054', '9019032279281346301', '954752930319787116', '958845616512015696', '988062287542814249'}

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that you can't do so many queries? It's a standard approach to the performing full scan of the Cassandra cluster. You only need to be careful in your implementation:

- Don't issue too many queries - maybe scan one token range in a time per server
- You need to set routing key explicitly when issuing the query - usually drivers aren't able to detect routing key for queries that use `token` function, so they send query to random coordinator node. So it should be done manually, and as I see, [Gocql supports setting of the routing key](https://github.com/gocql/gocql/blob/master/session.go#L751).
- You need correctly handle begin/end of the full range, otherwise you can get duplicates, or miss some data.

I'm not Go expert, but I have [an example in Java on how to perform full scan](https://github.com/alexott/dse-java-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/jdtest1/TokenRangesScan.java) for Cassandra database - you can grab a logic from it.

P.S. 256 tokens per server was a default for 2.x-3.x versions of Cassandra, but isn't recommended anymore. The default value will be changed in 4.0

Comment: For Point 1: Don't issue too many queries - maybe scan one token range in a time per server: 

There are too many ranges for the cluster to fir one range at a time which seems infeasible.

For 2: Its an API where i need to fetch all records so routing key is not possible as the driver doesn't support 

For 3: Too many ranges so querying on range seems too much for the job

Comment: I saw the code you pointed out it is essentially creating query for all ranges and getting data for each one of them , The only problem i can see is too many IO between application and Db , which would cause performance problems in the API response. Though that's the only way remains for solving this problem.

Comment: Usually, show all records operation is bad use case for Cassandra. It shines by reading a row or partition

Comment: True, i was trying to apply CQRS but there were too many restrictions in the current env..